# Sum of five lowest values

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I find the sum of the lowest five points in the Point column
and group by ID

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2PKQ.png)

The desired results should be;

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0dbq.png)

No idea where to start

Thanks

Comment: Do you want only the first five points in your table, or first five rows per id?

Comment: It usually helps to show the desired result. (And it would be nice to post the table as text, not as a picture, so we can copy and paste to work with the data.)

Comment: Thanks Thorsten for pointing this out, I have edited the question to show the desired results

Comment: @Sandet, the solution below attempts to do just that. Highlight if we face any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select a.ID, SUM(a.points) from(select ID , points,row_number() over 
    (partition by ID order by POINTS) as rownum_returned from your_table) a where 
a.rownum_returned<6  group by a.ID;
```

[Read about row_number() function here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If I've to do that I would solve it with a subquery.
In SQL server I will do subquery that retrieve the 5 lower point

```
Select Top 5 id, point from table
Order by point asc
```

Note: the keyword `TOP` that limit the result to the first 5
Note 2: order by point `asc` will order the result putting in top the lowest value

Now I use the query as subquery to complete the activity

```
Select id, sum (point) from
(Select top 5 id,point from table order by point asc) group by id
```

This should work

Comment: If I understand what you have stated correctly, this would only fetch the first five records in your database. It would not fetch the first five records of ID 1, then first five records of ID 2 and so on.